# JQuery opposite of extend (reduce objects)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing the next issue, I can merge/extend objects and works pretty well, but now I need to do the opposite of extending an object, JQuery doc:

```
var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: { weight: 52, price: 100 },
  cherry: 97
};
var object2 = {
  banana: { price: 200 },
  durian: 100
};

// Merge object2 into object1, recursively
$.extend( true, object1, object2 );

// Result
{"apple":0,"banana":{"weight":52,"price":200},"cherry":97,"durian":100}
```

Which is cool, and it works great, but how do I get the opposite operation, for example to get an output like this:

```
{"apple":0,"banana":{"weight":52},"cherry":97}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such function, but you can write your own:

```
$.prototype.reduce = function reduce(obj1, obj2) {
  for (var k in obj2) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(k) && obj2.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      if (typeof obj1[k] == "object" && typeof obj2[k] == "object") {
         reduce(obj1[k], obj2[k]);
      }
      else delete obj1[k];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this help with the nested `banana` object?

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two choices:

1. Remove the property using the `delete` operator.¹

   or
2. Create a new object without the property/properties you don't want.

Here's an example of using `delete`:¹

```js
const example = {
    a: "This is a",
    b: "This is b",
};
console.log("Before:", example);
delete example.a;
console.log("After:", example);
```

Here's an example of creating a new object without the property you don't want, using destructuring assignment and a rest element (added in ES2015; long-supported in all major environments):

```js
const example1 = {
    a: "This is a",
    b: "This is b",
};
console.log("Before:", example1);
const { a, ...example2 } = example1;
// New obj −−−^
console.log("After:", example2);
// Using the new obj −^
```

---

¹ 99.99% of the time it doesn't matter, but note that deleting properties from objects makes some JavaScript engines fall back on unoptimized "map" versions of objects instead of optimized ones, which means accessing the remaining properties on the object is much slower. Again, it's unusual that it matters, but useful to know for those very rare times when it does.

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered such a problem. I had to implement a recursive reduce operation:

```
$.reduce({a: 1, b: 2}, {b: 12, e: 13}) => {a: 1, b: 12}
```

Here is how i did it

```
$.reduce = function reduce(templateObj, toReduce, modifyCopy, doNotAppend) {
    if (!toReduce) {
        return toReduce;
    }
    if (!templateObj) {
        return toReduce;
    }
    // not changing the src toReduce
    var toModify = modifyCopy
        ? $.extend(true, {}, toReduce)
        : toReduce;

    // will append missing properties from templateObj 
    var merged = doNotAppend
        ? toModify
        : $.extend(true, {}, templateObj, toModify);
    // go through all the properties in toReduce or (templateObj + toReduce)
    $.each(merged, function (propName, value) {
        if (!(propName in templateObj)) {
            delete toModify[propName];
            return;
        }
        if (!(propName in toModify)) {
            toModify[propName] = templateObj[propName];
            return;
        }
        if (typeof templateObj[propName] == "object" && typeof toModify[propName] == "object") {
            toModify[propName] = $.reduce(templateObj[propName], toModify[propName]);
        }
    });
    return toModify;
}
```